# how to change fontsize using gdx BitmapFont

Tags: java, libgdx, bitmap-fonts

I created a font in java with BitmapFont

`private BitmapFont font = new BitmapFont(Gdx.`*`files`*`.internal("HARLOWSI.TTF"));`

now, I want to change the size of the font,

I tried the method `font.setScale(scale);` which appears in the BitmapFont methods,

it didn't work, so I looked for solutions online, I was told to try `font.getData().setScale(scale);`

but this does not work either.

I also tried this, but I get an error on the parameter.size line.
"Syntax error on token size, VariableDeclaratorID expected after this token"

```
package com.mygdx.game;

import java.lang.reflect.Parameter;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.freetype.FreeTypeFontGenerator;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.freetype.FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter;

public class Points {
    FreeTypeFontGenerator generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal("HARLOWSI.TTF"));
    FreeTypeFontParameter parameter = new FreeTypeFontParameter();
    parameter.size = 12; //here's where I get an error
    private String name;
    private int quantity;
    private Texture icon;
    private BitmapFont font = new BitmapFont();
    
    public Points(String name, int quantity, Texture icon) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.icon = icon;
        this.font = font;
    }
    
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }
    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }
    public Texture getIcon() {
        return icon;
    }
    public void setIcon(Texture icon) {
        this.icon = icon;
    }
    
    public void add(int added) {
        this.setQuantity(this.quantity+added);
    }
    public void substract(int substracted) {
        this.add(-substracted);
    }
    
    public void show(SpriteBatch batch) {
        batch.draw(this.icon, 10, 890-this.icon.getHeight());
        this.font.draw(batch, "Points : " + String.valueOf(this.quantity) , 20+this.icon.getWidth(),890-this.icon.getHeight());
    }
    
    public void show(SpriteBatch batch,int x, int y) {
        batch.draw(this.icon, x, y);
        this.font.draw(batch, "Points : " + String.valueOf(this.quantity) , 20+this.icon.getWidth(),890-this.icon.getHeight());
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use the `FreeTypeFontGenerator`, [documentation](https://libgdx.com/wiki/extensions/gdx-freetype), it allows you to generate a `BitmapFont` at a certain size.

That way you can generate several instances of the `BitmapFont`, one for each size you need in your game.

In your case the problem comes from you doing this

```
parameter.size = 12;
```

outside of the constructor (or method), it is a syntax error to do anything but declare variables there.

Move that line into your constructor instead;

```
public Points(String name, int quantity, Texture icon) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.quantity = quantity;
    this.icon = icon;
    this.font = font;
    
    parameter.size = 12;
}
```

Comment: I tried to use this, but when I try to change the field size with parameter.size=12;  , I get"Syntax error on token size, VariabledeclaratorID expected after this token.

Comment: Can you, @arthurmoiret, show the code you use to construct your fonts?
Here is an example of how I do it for a game, and setting `.size` works fine: https://github.com/bornander/lala/blob/master/core/src/com/bornander/lala/assets/FontAssets.java

Comment: Done. I really don't know where the problem comes from, my code is exactly the same, I may have missed something

Comment: I've update my answer, @arthurmoiret, to cover your precise problem.